# Unix checking current pathname a directory

Tags: unix

I am using Korn Shell and trying to write a scrip that will tell if the current pathname is a directory, and if so i am going to run some more commands. I have tried doing it with a IF statement but have been told this is better suited with using a WHILE statement. However I have no luck.

Comment: What's wrong with `test -d`? And indeed `if` is the right statement to use in this case.

Answer (score 0):

So... trying something like:

```
if [[ -d 'path' ]]; then
    <commands>
fi
```

didn't work?

Maybe you could also post an example with your code.

Comment: I tested with this. I used $DIRECTORY instead of 'path'. This is for a assignment but the directions tell me to check the current pathname to determine if it is a directory. How can I not be in a directory?